# Importing python module on start of RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, reticulate

I was pleased to find that `reticulate` allows me to import local python modules from a path. I wanted to add the call

```
reticulate::import_from_path('src', 'my_path')
```

to my `.Rprofile` file so I would not have to run this every time I want to use the module. This call works just fine as the first input to a fresh R console. When it's in the `.Rprofile` file we get some crashy message:

[image: It broke R!!!]

This doesn't happen with a couple other libraries that I tried. I can put `tibble::tibble(a = 1)` into the `.Rprofile` without issue.

I can't decipher this. Any idea why this is happening or how to prevent it?

Comment: File an issue on their GH repo maybe? What version of R and RStudio is this with?

Comment: R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18), RStudio Version 1.4.1103

Thanks for the suggestion, I may do that if I don't find a better alternative @Phil

Comment: I would first update RStudio (R has a newer version but it shouldn't matter) and try again, and if it's still occurring file an issue.